# English Language Learners Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](//ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

[image: A T-SHIRT!]

T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!

[image: STICKERS!]

STICKERS!!!!!!!

I'll be reaching out to you shortly with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

Thanks to all of you for making this site great!

Comment: @Bookend Some random person that modeled that t-shirt for the company we order from.

Comment: This page links to [a size chart](https://districtclothing.com/fit-guide/) with men's and women's sizes, but the page only lets you pick a size, not men's or women's.  Which sizes should I be looking at on the chart?

Comment: @snailplane We always use mens sizes unless the gender is explicitly selectable.

Comment: I am so tempted to edit out that closing "thanks"… must. restrain. reflexes!

Comment: Will the swag be going to the current top 72 users, or the top 72 users at the time of graduation?

Comment: I think the former @DJMc.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a mug. Do some sites get the mug and some don't?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think that you deserve a "fluff buster" badge for all of the work you put in succinctifying questions :)

Comment: If someone were to receive that email and didn't want the stuff, could I pass and have another person selected for it?

Comment: @TIPS Yes, I want a mug. A mug!! Please, mugs ... !

Comment: I haven't been reached out to. Have I missed something or is it yet to happen?

Comment: Should we don the t-shirts and post our photos as replies to this message? ^_^